# Using tags in DocFX markdown frontmatter / YAML header

Tags: docfx

I have a DocFX site with a number of pages. I would like to include tags at the top of each page via custom template, and I'd like for authors to be able to add tags in the YAML frontmatter, e.g.:

```
---
title: My Page Title
tags: tag1;tag2;tag3
---
```

I would then like to be able to access those tags as some sort of array and process them when generating the HTML output.

I've read the docs [here](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/spec/docfx_document_schema.html) which suggests that I can add a `schema.json` file somewhere and this will automatically detect items in the schema. What I can't work out is how to access the YAML frontmatter in my template when generating the output.

If I need to write a custom .NET plugin to do this then that isn't an issue, but I believe I should be able to access these properties in the template somehow.

Any guidance at all would be very gratefully-received!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to eventually work this out.

In my custom template I have a `conceptual.html.primary.tmpl` file which provides access to the frontmatter:

```
<div id="tags">
  {{#tags}}{{tags}}{{/tags}}
</div>
```

Obviously I now need to process the tags, but I now get HTML produced as expected from my `.md` files:

```html
<div id="tags">
    tag1;tag2;tag3
</div>
```

Comment: How do you process the tags?

Comment: In the `conceptual.extension.js` file in the theme dir, I extended the code to transform the model. Something like this: https://gist.github.com/phoenixx/f86124fb2f9a9e722a37f2f09663f1f3